# Which powershell module does the Get-PrivacyManagementRule command fall in?

Tags: powershell, security, microsoft365, o365security-compliance, cloud-security

I've been trying to figure out how a few security settings in M365 tenant can be configured via Powershell.
I was looking into Privacy Management in the admin console which has a bunch of settings I required, for eg- data retention period for subject right requests.
I was not able to find anything in the Microsoft documentations, but by some hit and trial I found a command - **Get-PrivacyManagementRule** . Turns out it has a lot of settings I was looking for.
I'm currently not sure whether I can use this command or this will eventually be deprecated since there is literally 0 information about this command from Microsoft.
Can anyone with more info on this help me out ?

Comment: Try this: Get-Command Get-PrivacyManagementRule

Comment: Not sure about that specific cmdlet, but might you be looking for something more like Get-RetentionPolicy?

Comment: Get-RetentionPolicy will give me the retention set for the normal data. I'm looking for the retention period for the data and reports during a Subject Rights Request.
You can find that option in the UI at :
Compliance portal-> Solutions-> Privacy Risk Management-> Data Profile-> Settings-> Data retention periods